# Pcie completion timeout

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, pci-e

when a pcie read request is given,the FPGA will respond with a delay(due to the delay in reading from custom component in FPGA).Due to this i am getting full 'ff' most of the times. Is it posiible to make the read wait. Does this have anything to do with the pcie completion timeout value.

used the command
sudo setpci -s01:00.0 CAP_EXP+0x28.W=0x0000

i set CTO value using this in the driver
pcie_capability_clear_and_set_word(dev, PCI_EXP_DEVCTL2, PCI_EXP_DEVCTL2_COMP_TIMEOUT, 0xd);

output:

$ sudo lspci -vv -s 01:00.0 | grep -A1 DevCtl2
DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 4s to 13s, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-

Comment: This is not what you asked, but perhaps you can consider using DMA to workaround this issue.